# Auto-wrap lots of items in Material

Tags: angularjs, material-design

In bootstrap, I would be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="myData in myArray"></div>
</div>
```

And if I had, say, 8 items in `myArray`, I would get output kinda like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
5 | 6 | 7 | 8
```

When I try to do this with material/angular, all I get is this:
[image]

... which obviously isn't wrapping.

Here's my HTML:

```
<md-card>
  <h3 class="text-center">Stats</h3>
  <div layout="horizontal" class="text-center">
    <div ng-repeat="stat in equipmentStatArray" flex="25">
        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-2x vertical-center {{stat.fa}}">
            <md-tooltip>{{stat.name}}</md-tooltip>
        </span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>{{player._statCache[stat.name]}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-card>
```

Is this possible with Material?

Comment: I think it the other way around. Your `col-md-3` div should be a parent of `ng-repeat` one.

Comment: I goofed on that syntax. Updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that, or you can simply add `layout-wrap` property to your `<div ng-repeat="stat in equipmentStatArray" flex="25">` like this:

`<div ng-repeat="stat in equipmentStatArray" flex="25" layout-wrap>`

Comment: I came across this once again via google, and this is the right way to do this now.

Answer (score 0):

As luck would have it, this is just a flexbox thing. I solved it with some combination of `flex-wrap: wrap`, `display: flex`, and setting my own flex attributes (at the time of posting, angular-material had set the flex attributes incorrectly. This has since been corrected).